# XML Parsing using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, parsing

I am trying to parse an xml file using powershell. I want to print each node and its subnodes. I am new to xml parsing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Inventory>
  <Roles>
    <Role Name="VirtualMachinePowerUser" Label="Virtual machine power user (sample)" Summary="Provides virtual machine interaction and configuration permissions">
      <Privilege Name="Datastore.Browse" />
      <Privilege Name="Global.CancelTask" />
      <Privilege Name="ScheduledTask.Create" />
</Role>
    <Role Name="VirtualMachineUser" Label="Virtual machine user (sample)" Summary="Provides virtual machine interaction permissions">
      <Privilege Name="Global.CancelTask" />
      <Privilege Name="ScheduledTask.Create" />
</Role>
```

My code below

```
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "C:\RolesnPer.xml"     
$nodelist = $inputFile.Inventory.Roles.Role |Select-Object -Property Name
foreach ($Role in $nodelist)
{
    $Role
    $XMLprinterPath = $Role.selectSingleNode("Privilege").get_innerXml()
}
```

Required output:

```
Name                      Privilege
VirtualMachinePowerUser   Datastore.Browse
                          Global.CancelTask
                          ScheduledTask.Create
VirtualMachineUser        Global.CancelTask
                          ScheduledTask.Create
```

But I am getting this output:

```
Name
----
VirtualMachinePowerUser
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'selectSingleNode'.
At C:\Mandy\Code\transformation.ps1:25 char:1
+ $XMLprinterPath = $Role.selectSingleNode("Privilege").get_innerXml()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (selectSingleNode:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

VirtualMachineUser
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Xml.XmlElement] does not contain a method named 'selectSingleNode'.
At C:\Mandy\Code\transformation.ps1:25 char:1
+ $XMLprinterPath = $Role.selectSingleNode("Privilege").get_innerXml()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (selectSingleNode:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Deadrobot's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56056838/45375) diagnoses your problem correctly (`Select-Object` emits `[pscustomobject]` instances, not XML nodes), but there's a simpler solution:

```sh
Select-Xml -LiteralPath C:\RolesnPer.xml '//Role' | ForEach-Object {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    Name = $_.Node.Name
    Privilege = $_.Node.Privilege.Name
  }
}
```

The above yields:

```
Name                    Privilege
----                    ---------
VirtualMachinePowerUser {Datastore.Browse, Global.CancelTask, ScheduledTask.Create}
VirtualMachineUser      {Global.CancelTask, ScheduledTask.Create}
```

Explanation:

- The `Select-Xml` cmdlet can operate on files directly for extracting matching nodes with XPath queries.
- Each matching node can be accessed via `$_.Node` inside the `ForEach-Object` script block, and PowerShell conveniently exposes the child elements and attributes of XML element nodes as direct properties, so that `.Name` reports the value of the `Name` attribute, and `.Privilege` returns all `Privilege` child elements as an array, and, thanks to [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), accessing their `.Name` property returns an array of all their `Name` attributes.
- `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is PSv3+ syntactic sugar for constructing a custom object using hashtable syntax.

Note: While the **output format is *not* exactly what you asked for**, **outputting *objects*** (rather than using string formatting) gives you **more flexibility for subsequent programmatic processing**.

---

If you do need the **exact output format specified in your question**:

```sh
# The format string to use with the -f operator below.
# The first column is 30 chars. wide; adjust as needed.
$fmtStr = '{0,-30} {1}'

# Output the header line.
$fmtStr -f 'Name', 'Privilege'

# Query the XML document and output the data lines.
Select-Xml -LiteralPath t.xml '//Role' | ForEach-Object {
  $name = $_.Node.Name
  foreach ($priv in $_.Node.Privilege.Name) {
    $fmtStr -f $name, $priv
    $name = ''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is occurs because `Select-Object` on line 2 creates a new object that isn't xml.

I'm not an expert on manipulation XML, so there probably is a better way, but I would code it as such to get the output you want:

```bsh
[xml]$inputFile = Get-Content "C:\RolesnPer.xml"  
$Nodelist = $inputFile.SelectNodes("//Role")
$ParsedOutput = @()
foreach ($Role in $Nodelist) {
    $Name = $Role.Name
    $Privilege = $Role.Privilege |Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
    $Obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Name
    $Obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Privilege -Value $Privilege
    $ParsedOutput += $Obj
}

$ParsedOutput
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help

Answer (score 1):

I know that answers have already been provided on accessing the element data, but this post is mainly to address the output formatting request:

```
$inputFile = [xml](Get-Content "C:\RolesnPer.xml")
$nodes = $inputFile.Inventory.Roles.Role | Select-Object -Property Name,Privilege
$NameColWidth = ($nodes.name | Foreach-Object { $_.length } | Sort-Object -Desc)[0] + 2
$FormattedOutput = @("{0,-$NameColWidth}{1}" -f "Name","Privilege") -as [collections.arraylist]
foreach ($node in $nodes) {
    $null = $FormattedOutput.Add(("{0,-$NameColWidth}{1}" -f $node.name,($node.privilege.name | Select-Object -First 1)))
    $node.Privilege | Select -expand Name -skip 1 | Foreach-Object {
        $null = $FormattedOutput.Add(("{0,-$NameColWidth}{1}" -f " ",$_))
    }
}
$FormattedOutput
```

If you only want the PowerShell object array with the two properties (Name and Privilege) without formatting, you only need the first two lines. Then output the variable `$nodes`.

Comment: Thanks A lot this is what i expected i got the same result